# Assigning values to a 2D array using "each" method

Tags: ruby, arrays, variable-assignment

I'm trying to transpose `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]`. I get `[[2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 8]]`.

I can see what is happening with the line `p transposed_arr` but do not understand why this is happening. At every iteration it changes every row instead of only one.

```
def my_transpose(arr)
  # number of rows
  m = arr.count

  #number of columns
  n = arr[0].count

  transposed_arr = Array.new(n, Array.new(m))

  # loop through the rows
  arr.each_with_index do |row, index1|

      # loop through the colons of one row
      row.each_with_index do |num, index2|

          # swap indexes to transpose the initial array
          transposed_arr[index2][index1] = num
          p transposed_arr
      end
  end
  transposed_arr
end
```

Comment: Now that your code is working, consider posting it at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get suggestions for improvements. If you've not been there before, I think you'd be impressed by the advice dispensed there. Many of the questions posted there are from newbies, so it's not the least bit intimidating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make only one wee change and your method will work fine. Replace:

```
transposed_arr = Array.new(n, Array.new(m))
```

with:

```
transposed_arr = Array.new(n) { Array.new(m) }
```

The former makes `transposed_arr[i]` the same object (an array of size `m`) for all `i`. The latter creates a separate array of size `m` for each `i`

Case 1:

```
transposed_arr = Array.new(2, Array.new(2))
transposed_arr[0].object_id
  #=> 70235487747860 
transposed_arr[1].object_id
  #=> 70235487747860
```

Case 2:

```
transposed_arr = Array.new(2) { Array.new(2) }
transposed_arr[0].object_id
  #=> 70235478805680 
transposed_arr[1].object_id
  #=> 70235478805660
```

With that change your method returns:

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8]]
```